# Working through third party code, C# deciphering

Tags: c#

I am working through some C# code in an attempt to see what is going on. I have reached a section of interest and I am curious to know what this conditional is saying. I am not very well-versed in C# and was wondering if somebody could essentially translate this line into English.

```
if (!executeItemCommand._container.Adapters.Where<IAdapter>((Func<IAdapter, bool>)
 (i_X => i_X.Identity.Equals("MeasureViews"))).Any<IAdapter>())
```

Comment: "If this `executeItemCommand` does not contain any adapters with an `.Identity` of `MeasureViews`, then..." or even more succinctly "if `executeItemCommand` has no `MeasureViews` adapter..."

Comment: Who would write in such style?

Comment: @JeroenMostert I am now trying to read what you said and "connect" it to the syntax of the code. Thank you.

Comment: @BogdanDoicin Perhaps, this is decompiled source code, because it looks exactly like a decompiled source.

Comment: @BogdanDoicin this is a third party app that keeps crashing at a particular point and I am trying to see if I can find an issue in some of the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Originally, this could should has been something like this:

```
!executeItemCommand._container.Adapters.Any(a => a.Identity.Equals("MeasureViews"))
```

This condition checks if there are no adapters in the container with `Identity` equal to "MeasureViews". So, it will return `false` if there is any.

You may be interested in this documentation on LINQ `.Any()` at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.7.2) for further learning.

Just as a comment, imho this would actually be cleaner to rewrite it this way:

```
executeItemCommand._container.Adapters.All(a => !a.Identity.Equals("MeasureViews"))
```

Comment: The original code would probably be `!executeItemCommand._container.Adapters.Where(a => a.Identity == "MeasureViews").Any()` (assuming `.Identity` is actually a `string`). Shifting the condition to the `.Any()` changes the actual calls. Exactly what variation is "cleaner" is highly subjective, of course, there's lots of ways to write this.

Comment: Thank you both, you have made this more clear to me. After working a lot with VB.NET recently, I have been awaiting the transition to C#.